# Задать процент выпадения варианта

Tags: python

Как задать процент выпадения каждого варианта? Мне надо чтоб процент выпадения был 30%/50%/20%.

```
print(random.choice(["пройдёт", "состоится", "будет сыгран"]))
```

Comment: ну выбираете число от одного до ста и делаете условия по типу `if num <=30: ваши действия`

Comment: `random.choices(yourList, weights=(30, 50, 20), k=1)` ? обратите внимание на название метода - есть `choice`, а есть `choices`.

Comment: @strawdog, а что значит ```k=1```?

Comment: а почитайте документацию. там все написано.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо